# Custom drop-in icons for DMG background for application packaging on MacOSX

Tags: java, macos, javafx-2, packaging, app-bundle

I'm having trouble adding custom icons for a DMG background in a self-contained package built on MacOSX. I have added a package in the root directory of my project. The custom icon is getting loaded from it, but the DMG background icon isn't. I am using Java fx 2.2.3 and jdk1.7.0_09. Here is the verbose output generated for the same.

```
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.2 Launching <fx:jar> task from
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar
Launching <fx:deploy> task from
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar
Copying 102 files to
/Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication2/dist Using base JDK
at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk Using default
package resource [Bundle config file] (add package/macosx/Info.plist
to the class path to customize) Using custom package resource [icon]
(loaded from file
/Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication2/package/macosx/javaFXApplication2.icns)
Creating app bundle:
/Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication2/dist/bundles/JavaFXApplication2.app
Config files are saved to
/var/folders/vd/nyxf14z53tx56g2_lbqcnfrr0000gn/T/build1722966263281326253.fxbundler/macosx.
Use them to customize package. Building DMG package for
JavaFXApplication2 Using default package resource [Bundle config
file] (add package/macosx/Info.plist to the class path to customize)
Using custom package resource [icon] (loaded from file
/Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication2/package/macosx/javaFXApplication2.icns)
Config files are saved to
/var/folders/vd/nyxf14z53tx56g2_lbqcnfrr0000gn/T/build1722966263281326253.fxbundler/macosx.
Use them to customize package. Using default package resource [dmg
background] (add package/macosx/JavaFXApplication2-background.png to
the class path to customize) Using custom package resource [volume
icon] (loaded from file
/Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication2/package/macosx/javaFXApplication2.icns)
Using default package resource [script to run after application
image is populated] (add
package/macosx/JavaFXApplication2-post-image.sh to the class path to
customize) Using default package resource [DMG setup script] (add
package/macosx/JavaFXApplication2-dmg-setup.scpt to the class path
to customize) Result DMG installer for JavaFXApplication2:
/Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication2/dist/bundles/JavaFXApplication2.dmg
Config files are saved to
/var/folders/vd/nyxf14z53tx56g2_lbqcnfrr0000gn/T/build1722966263281326253.fxbundler/macosx.
Use them to customize package.
```

Here is the directory where all my icon files are listed:-

```
Apples-MacBook-Pro-2:~ apple$ ls -l /Users/apple/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApplication2/package/macosx/
total 136
-rw-r--r--@ 1 apple staff 1251 Nov 1 19:02 Info.plist
-rw-r--r-- 1 apple staff 18017 Nov 1 18:22 JavaFXApplication2-background.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 apple staff 902 Nov 2 13:55 JavaFXApplication2-dmg-setup.scpt
-rw-r--r-- 1 apple staff 38115 Jan 19 2006 JavaFXApplication2.icns
```

As you can see, the icon gets loaded from the package but the DMG background file isn't, even though I have added that file in the same directory as well.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but with the `.icns` file as well. Interested if a fix is found. I wish one could just specify the path directly, or somehow debug the resource resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Backgrounds for folders in OS X are set in the .DS_Store file by the Finder.  If you're careful not to change the folder path and name of the background file, you can set the background image using the Finder and then copy the .DS_Store file and copy it over during the build process.  If you want something better, we use this Perl script to set backgrounds on folders (it relies on some other Perl libraries, you should be able to find them).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Mac::Finder::DSStore::BuddyAllocator;
use Mac::Finder::DSStore;
use IO::File;
use Data::Dumper;
use Config;
use Mac::Files;
use Mac::Memory;
use Mac::Finder::DSStore qw( writeDSDBEntries makeEntries );
use Sys::Filesystem::ID;
use File::Basename;

die "Usage: $0 <Folder path> <bg path relative to folder>\n"
    unless @ARGV == 2;

$folderPath=$ARGV[0];
while ($folderPath =~ /\/$/)
{
    chop($folderPath);
}

die "$folderPath is not a directory" unless -d $folderPath;
$bgPath=$folderPath."/".$ARGV[1];
die "$bgPath is not a file" unless -f $bgPath;

# When we're setting the background for the root, the info lives
# in the .DS_Store file in the directory, otherwise it lives in
# the parent directory
if (Sys::Filesystem::ID::_arg_to_mount_point($folderPath) eq $folderPath)
{
    $dsStoreFile=$folderPath."/.DS_Store";
    $ourName=".";
}
else
{
    $dsStoreFile=$folderPath."/../.DS_Store";
    ($ourName, $path, $suffix) = fileparse($folderPath);
}

#print "Setting bg for $folderPath to $bgPath, .DS_Store file = $dsStoreFile ourName=$ourName\n";
#We use byFilename to keep track of the records for everybody
# we will pull out the records for . and remove any BKGD records
@otherRecs=();
@ourRecs=();
if (-f $dsStoreFile)
{
    $store = Mac::Finder::DSStore::BuddyAllocator->open(new IO::File $dsStoreFile, '<');
    @records=&Mac::Finder::DSStore::getDSDBEntries($store);
    foreach my $curRec (@records)
    {
        if ($curRec->filename ne $ourName)
        {
            push(@otherRecs, $curRec);
        }
        else
        {
            push(@oldRecs, $curRec);
        }
    }
    if ( @oldRecs != 0)
    {
        foreach $curRec(@oldRecs)
        {
            if ($curRec->strucId ne "BKGD" && $curRec->strucId ne "pict" && $curRec->strucId ne "bwsp" && $curRec->strucId ne "icvp")
            {
                push(@ourRecs, $curRec);
            }
        }
    }

}
undef $store;
if ($ourRec == 0)
{
    push(@ourRecs, &makeEntries($ourName, ICVO => 1,
            icvo => pack('A4 n A4 A4 n*', "icv4", 48, "none", "botm", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 100, 1)));
}
@bgRecs=&makeEntries($ourName, BKGD_alias => NewAliasMinimal($bgPath));
@ourRecs=(@ourRecs,@bgRecs);
&writeDSDBEntries($dsStoreFile, @ourRecs, @otherRecs);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried CHMODing it? I've found this to be the issue with similar experiences.

```
chmod 777 backgroundpathhere
```

In terminal. (Just incase you don't know)